# IF True, copy other cell/IF False, move to next record

Tags: vba, excel

**Warning...this explanation is a little long**

I am working on autopopulating a report (Failure Report) based on a failure count in a separate worksheet (Results, Col H).  The failure count (Results) is a countif function that determines the number of failures (based on Fail and Pass) in a range of 3 columns (Results, D:F) and outputs the count in another column (Results, Col H).

My current problem is writing either a nested function or a script that will check to see if the failure count is greater than zero.  If it is True (there has been a "fail" entered), copy Item number (Results, col A) and Description (Results, Col B) into the failure report (Failure Report, Col A and B respectively) and do nothing if it is false (there has been a "pass" entered).

In short...I want to populate the Failure Report with the Item Number and Description for **only** the items that have "fail" in the failure count column (Results, Col H) and have no empty rows between entries on the Failure Report.

**Update**

My current solution was to use an advanced filter for the solitary table and filter by True/False (whether there was a pass/fail in Cols D:F).  My new problem is creating a VBA script to copy the filtered range and paste it to the Failure Report.  I have the filter and copy scripts separate.  The filter script works perfectly...but the copy script is giving me an error stating "Run-Time error '1004'  The extract range has a missing or illegal field name."  I am fairly experienced with Excel, but I am learning VB/VBA as I progress.

Filter Script

```
Sub Button2_Click()
'PURPOSE: Filter on specific values


Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:I962")
FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("False", rng.Rows(1), 0)

'Turn on filter if not already turned on
 If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter

'Filter Specific values
 rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=Array( _
"False"), Operator:=xlFilterValues



End Sub
```

Copy Script

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Dim rng As Range

'Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:I962")

Sheets("Results").Select
Sheets("Results").Range("A2,B2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Failure Report").Select
Sheets("Failure Report").Range("I21:J21").PasteSpecial
'Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'Sheets("Failure Report").Range("Z4").Select
Sheets("Results").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("J34").Select
Sheets("Failure Report").Activate
Sheets("Results").Range("A3:I962").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Results").Range("J1:J2"), _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Failure Report").Range("I22:J22"), Unique:=True
Selection.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better if you'll share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I gather from your text that the Filter Script successfully filters out the rows of interest.  I do not understand the Copy Script.  You start by selecting  A2 and B2 of "Results" and copying then to "Failure Report".  I cannot see anything that uses the filtered range in "Results".  What are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: The Filter Script does work as intended.  The copy script is to copy the filtered results from "Results" worksheet range (A3:I962) and the headers and paste them onto "Failure Report." My end-game is to filter out the "True" values from the Results sheet and paste those values into the Failure Report with the click of a macro-enabled button (or two).

Comment: I have added some code to my "answer".  Please try that code and tell me what it does.

Comment: "Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference."  I believe it was expecting another command when assigning the variable...but I am new to VBA and it might be different than other languages like C# or HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer.  It is an attempt to extract the important facts from your text.

```
   ------ Sheet3 ------       Another sheet (?)
   D   E   F      G/H         X     Y
  xxx xxx xxx      a          if a>0 then values from columns A and B else no entry for row
  xxx xxx xxx      b          if b>0 then values from columns A and B else no entry for row
  xxx xxx xxx      c          if c>0 then values from columns A and B else no entry for row
                              if d>0 then values from columns A and B else no entry for row
  xxx xxx xxx      d

  Formulae      Failure
 summarising     counts
 information    derived
from elsewhere  from D:F
```

You have 32 tables.  The number of these tables, their location in another worksheet and their prior location in three worksheets is not relevant to this question.

Columns D:F of Sheet 3 contain formulae summarising information from the 32 tables.  In my "diagram", I have said "elsewhere" because the nature of these formulae and the location of their source data is not relevant.  These columns can contain blanks.  The "xxx"s can be either "Pass" or "Fail".

In paragraphs 1 and 2 you say column H contains the failure count.  In paragraph 4 you say it is column G.  Whichever column it is, it contains a count of the number of "Fails" in columns D:F so the value could be 0, 1, 2 or 3.  Because there are gaps in columns D:F, there are gaps in column G/H.

I do not know the location of columns X and Y but they are the columns you wish to fill. If column G/H is greater than zero, Column A and B of Sheet 3 are to be copied to columns X and Y.  Unlike other columns, there are to be no gaps in these columns.  In column G/H is zero or if it is blank, nothing will be copied to columns X and Y.

The above is my attempt to tease your requirement from your text.  I suspect it could be reduced further because I do not think columns D:F are relevant.  You have columns A, B and G/H.  Column G/H can contain 0, 1, 2, 3 or blank.  If column G/H has a value of 1. 2 or 3 then copy coluns A and B to columns X and Y.  There are to be no blank rows Columns X and Y for rows for which column G/H is 0 or blank.

You should revise your question so it only contains relevant information.

---

I use VBA as a convenient programming language; I am not an expert on Excel and its formulae.  I do not believe you can achieve your objective with formulae however an Excel expert may respond with a solution if your question is clear and limited to relevant information.

In VBA this would be a simple loop that ran down column G/H and copied data if it is 1, 2 or 3. Have a go at coding that loop then come back here for help if you have any difficulties.

---

Without seeing the data, I do not have a clear picture of what is happening.  Please add the following to the top of `CommandButton1_Click` and tell me what it does:

```
  Dim RngCopy As Range

  Set rngCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

  RngCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Failure Report").Range("A21")
```

Comment: I have revised my question and included two scripts that I am working with.

Comment: I got it to work. I had to tweak the objects a bit. The only issue is it now states that it cannot change part of a merged cell...but the script works as desired.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction...and then some.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested...I was able to get the macros (all three of them) to work successfully.

Filter Values Macro

```
Sub FilterValues()
'PURPOSE: Filter on specific values

 Dim rng As Range

 Set rng = Sheets("Results").Range("A3:J962")
 FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("False", rng.Rows(1), 0)

 'Turn on filter if not already turned on
  If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter

 'Filter Specific values
  rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=Array( _
  "False"), Operator:=xlFilterValues    

End Sub
```

Copy Values of an Advanced Sorted Table

```
Sub CopyValues()

 'Declare Variables
  Dim rngCopy As Range
  Dim rngCopyNotes As Range

 'Set Variables
  Set rngCopy = Sheets("Results").Range("A3:B962").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  Set rngCopyNotes = Sheets("Results").Range("I3:J962").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

 'Set destination for variables
  rngCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Failure Report").Range("A22")
  rngCopyNotes.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Failure Report").Range("H22")

 'Copy headers and values
  Sheets("Results").Activate
  Sheets("Results").Range("A2:B2").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("Failure Report").Select
  Sheets("Failure Report").Range("A21:B21").PasteSpecial

  Sheets("Results").Activate
  Sheets("Results").Range("J2,I2").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("Failure Report").Select
  Sheets("Failure Report").Range("H21:I21").PasteSpecial

 'Autofit columns A through H
 'Columns("A:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit

  Sheets("Failure Report").Range("F12").Select
  Sheets("Results").Activate
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Range("N34").Select
  Sheets("Failure Report").Activate

End Sub
```

Word Wrap Macro

```
Sub WordWrap()

 ' WordWrap Macro

 Sheets("Failure Report").Activate
 Columns("I:I").Select
 With Selection
     .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
     .WrapText = True
     .Orientation = 0
     .AddIndent = False
     .IndentLevel = 0
     .ShrinkToFit = False
     .ReadingOrder = xlContext
     .MergeCells = False
 End With


 Columns("B:B").Select
 With Selection
     .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
     .WrapText = True
     .Orientation = 0
     .AddIndent = False
     .IndentLevel = 0
     .ShrinkToFit = False
     .ReadingOrder = xlContext
     .MergeCells = False
 End With
End Sub
```

I know these three macros are not exactly streamlined and there is probably a bit of filler that can either be removed or truncated.

Thank you for the assistance and also leading me in the correct direction to learn and adapt my prior macros.